# Using lapply()-function to find the mean of every row in data frame in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame consisting of 36 observations of 7 variables (Technology, Sector, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014). Variable 1 and 2 are of type "factor" and variables 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 are numeric with some NAs.

I want to use the lapply()-function to find the mean of every row (the mean of variable 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 per row) and then create a new column (cbind) with those means.

Can this be done, like for example with a matrix and an apply()-function, where you can specify row vs column - selection:

```
apply(matrix, 1, mean) #will go through all the rows and calculate the mean for each one.
```

Comment: It is a task for my online intermediate course. We have to do it in 3 different ways, one of which is using one of the lapply/apply/sapply or tapply. The first way is using rowMeans :)

Comment: Tell course instructor, this may be a trick question because for data frames, aggregations like mean should run by columns (not rows). This wide data set should be reshaped to long format with indicator column for years and values in adjacent columns and then run groupwise means.

Comment: The very idea of a data set (well beyond R) is that every column is a different type and this diversity together allows for intuition on units of observations (i.e., rows). Rowwise operations *should* fail as data sets do not guarantee same types *between* each other, only *within*. Otherwise use a matrix where all elements are the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, OP mentioned to use either of `lapply/apply/sapply or tapply`, hence a solution using `apply` can be as:

```
df$meanVal <- apply(df[3:7], 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The new column `meanVal` will contain `mean` for columns `3:7`

Answer (score 2):

The function `rowMeans` will be much more efficient:

```
df$meanVal <- rowMeans(df[3:7], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Using `lapply` on rows is not often necessary as `apply(dafa,1,fun)` works usually fine. But in some cases you might want :

```
lapply(split(data,seq(nrow(data))),fun)
```

or :

```
by(data,seq(nrow(data)),fun)
```